# undefined method `name' for "CloudyScripts":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

On Ubuntu and Ruby 1.8.7, I installed CloudyScripts via:

```
gem install CloudyScripts
```

When I try to execute this:

```
gem "CloudyScripts"
require "cloudyscripts"
```

I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `name' for "CloudyScripts":String
```

Why am I getting the error?

Comment: Why do you do `gem "CloudyScript"`?

Comment: I am doing setup the project which is in rails 2 and ruby 1.8.7  so  i am getting error to solve these error i install  gem "CloudyScript"

Comment: gem install, ok. but why do you have that line in the code? Try not using it.

Comment: i am try not using it but i getting same error when i fire rake gems:install command .